# Error :An attempt was made to add an object to the directory with a name that is already in use

Tags: powershell, error-handling, active-directory

if the user exist in AD.I am trying to add by adding 1 at end and then adding it to AD but it showing this exception

Answer (score 4):

It would be helpful if you show your code so we can see exactly what you are doing. But I suspect I might know.

There are 3 attributes that are enforced unique in AD:

1. `sAMAccountName` (commonly called the "username") has to be unique on the domain
2. `userPrincipalName` has to be unique in the forest
3. `cn` attribute (or the "name") has to be unique in the OU

So I suspect you added a "1" to one of them, but not all.

If you're not sure how to do that properly, then update your question with the code you are using and we can help.